# Visual studio extension that uploads code analysis warnings to a server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

This is what i want to achieve:

When a developer runs code analysis on his solution folder or on a project i want all the errors and warnings generated by code analysis to be transferred to a remote server. To to this i want to write an extension to visual studio. But don't have a single clue where to start. Any head-start regarding how to get code-analysis output (through code) and send it to a remote location, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/), that run the analysis and show it in a web based dashboard. The objective is of course to reuse your code analysis metrics there, which can be done using a plugin like [Analysis Bootstrapper](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Bootstrapper+for+Visual+Studio+Projects+Plugin).

The "IDE" use case and the "Dashboard" use case are for me both needed - one provides the convenience inside the tool, the other allows to check that everyone is following the common rules. It's also good if it runs without manual action, as most of us do not have the discipline to do it regularly on our own.

Comment: i know about `SonarQube`. But the idea here is to user `Code Analysis` that comes with `Visual Studio`. Anyway i have found a way to upload `Code Analysis` results into a remote server from each of the developers machine.

Comment: I may be mistaken (not a C# dev), but I think they can create their config based on one from Code Analysis (ie, so that you don't have to duplicate your settings).